# C error handling coding-style

Tags: c, error-handling, coding-style

In the case of the following code structure:

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    f1(...);
    f2(...);
    f3(...);
    f4(...);
    f5(...);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Which way of the error handling is more acceptable?

This:

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    if(f1(...)){
         // Error handling
         return ERROR;
    }

    if(f2(...)){
         // Error handling
         return ERROR;
    }

    ...

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Or this:

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    if(f1(...)){
        goto error;
    }

    if(f2(...)){
        goto error;
    }

    ...

    return SUCCESS;

error:
    // Error handling
    return ERROR;
}
```

Comment: You probably want separate questions for C and C++, since the error handling idioms will be very different for each.

Comment: this is a c question. c++ has better ways of error handling. the 2nd one is definitely not preferred in c. goto is synonymous with havoc. never use it. you have many ways to get around it.

Comment: I've seen both. The last time I've seen the `goto error` idiom it was corporate mandated coding style.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is it not better to use flags and such than the goto statement even though this is within the scope?

Comment: @Koushik As all questions about coding styles, this is very much personal. Unless mandated by others, do what you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C, I prefer your second option.

Further, it's useful to do gradual cleanup (free allocated memory and so on), like in Linux kernel:

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    if(f1(...)){
        goto error1;
    }

    if(f2(...)){
        goto error2;
    }

    ...

    return SUCCESS;

error2:
    cleanup2();

error1:
    cleanup1();

    // Error handling
    return ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    if (f1(...) && f2(...) && f3(...)  && f4(...) && f5(...)) 
        return SUCCESS;
    else
        return ERROR;
}
```

Comment: This complicates a bit reading and debugging, as you are not able to set breakpoint in a separate functions.

Comment: Thats true, but you can set breakpoint inside each function, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

In C, I'd use the third option:

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    bool ok = true;
    if (ok) ok = f1(...);
    if (ok) ok = f2(...);
    if (ok) ok = f3(...);
    if (ok) ok = f4(...);
    if (ok) ok = f5(...);

    if (!ok) error_handling();

    cleanup();  // Your example didn't have this, but it's often here.

    return ok ? SUCCESS : ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way i like to do is the following in c langage :

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    int res=0;

    if(f1(...)){
        goto ENDF;
    }

    if(f2(...)){
        goto ENDF;
    }

    ...

    res = 1;

ENDF:
   if(res ==0)
   {
      //Error handling
   } 

   //Success and Error stuff to do (like free...).

    return res;
}
```

So there is only one return, and sometimes there is some actions to do in both : error and success (such as free...).

I guess my point of view can be discussed.

Comment: This code would still invoke the error handling even if all the calls succeed.

Comment: add a `return success` above the error label. It will be correct, though not good.

Comment: I change it the real way i'm doing it... ( copy / paste mistake :/)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an exceptional thing that makes the function not work, throw an exception.

If you have reason to stick to a return code, you can use

```
if ( f1() && f2() && .... )
    return SUCCESS;
else
    return ERROR;
```

Execution will stop after the first `false` or `0` is encountered, so the effects are pretty much the same as your version.

Some libraries return `0` on success (heh, even C++'s `main` does so). So you might want

```
if ( !f1() &&.... )
```

or a simple

```
return f1() && f2() &&.... ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i normally use

```
int function_sequence(...)
{
    if(f1(...)){
        goto error1;
    }

    if(f2(...)){
        goto error2;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

error1:
    // Error 1 handling
    return -eerno1;

error2:
    // Error 2 handling
    return -eerno2;

//end of main
```

Comment: Is this valid C code? What is the context it is pasted from? `main`? I just can't seem to figure out whether you then have definition of `function_sequence` procedure inside the body of another procedure (context) or this is more of a pseude-code with some valid C syntax.